# EDITTEXT Android : Need to control the cursor position (prevent or allow)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am developing an app where I am facing the below issue:

Let's say I have the following expression : 5+9x6/6+SIN(8)+TAN(78) in a calculator app:

So, what I am trying to achieve is that if the editText's current cursor was just after the N in TAN or the N in SIN or the S in COS, and given that the user decided to delete SIN, or COS or TAN, I want to delete the whole String at once (without having the user to delete each of the 3 chars one by one.

That, I have managed to achieve using the below snippet:

```
 int cursorPosition = editTxt.getSelectionStart();
                try {
                    if (editTxt.getText().toString().substring(cursorPosition - 4, cursorPosition).equals("SIN") ||      ///runs if TAN, COS, or SIN were detected during deletion
                            editTxt.getText().toString().substring(cursorPosition - 4, cursorPosition).equals("COS") ||
                            editTxt.getText().toString().substring(cursorPosition - 4, cursorPosition).equals("TAN")) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        editTxt.setText(editTxt.getText().delete(cursorPosition - 4, cursorPosition));
                        editTxt.setSelection(cursorPosition - 4);
                    }else{
                        ///here is the regular char delete process
                        editTxt.setText(editTxt.getText().delete(cursorPosition-1,cursorPosition));
                        editTxt.setSelection(cursorPosition-1);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    editTxt.setText(editTxt.getText().delete(cursorPosition-1,cursorPosition));
                    editTxt.setSelection(cursorPosition-1);
                }
```

BUT THE ISSUE HERE IS: If the user decides to delete the "T" from TAN, then I need to find a way, to delete the rest of the "AN", in other words, I want to delete the whole string "TAN" if the user attempts to delete any of its chars, and the same for SIN and COS as well.

Attached is a short GIF showing what I am trying to achieve (taken from Google Calculator). (Basically I want to prevent the user from setting the placing the cursor anywhere in between the "TAN" , [The way it works in Google Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C6yG.gif)"COS" and "SIN"

Comment: If you are trying to copy a feature in open-source, why not look at the source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ExactCalculator/

Comment: @MorrisonChang The expression logic in that repo is super complicated, deprecated and probably completely useless for a beginner like him. Not sure that's helping in any way, perhaps he's just trying to learn?

Comment: Dears, with the snippet which I included, it only works as I want, only if the SIN, COS, or TAN strings were intact. But if the user deleted any of their chars, then that code will not work. I thought this would be a piece of cake for pros like you,

@MorrisonChang, can you provide me with a way to solve my problem? since you seem to be very knowledgeable. 

Comment: You are trying to delete text on both sides of a cursor. Editing at any single char is a property of EditText. Without creating your own custom View, basically you'll need to keep track of where each function name starts and ends when the user deletes separate from the display string and update that data structure every time a user types something. My guess is that Google Calc is displaying a custom view which doesn't allow the cursor to get inside the func name string, and that funcs are tokens not individual chars. If not familiar with tokens, start with a Reverse Polish Notation calculator.

Comment: Thanks Guys, but I was able to come up with a solution. I will post it as an answer to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who encountered the same scenario, below is my own simple workaround:

```
if(selEnd != this.getText().length()){
            String nextCharacter=this.getText().toString().substring(selStart,selStart+1);
            try {
                switch (nextCharacter) {
                    case "A":
                    case "O":
                    case "I":
                        MainActivity.currentPosition = selEnd + 3;
                        this.setSelection(MainActivity.currentPosition);
                        break;
                    case "N":
                        MainActivity.currentPosition = selEnd + 2;
                        this.setSelection(MainActivity.currentPosition);
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        if (this.getText().toString().charAt(selStart + 1) != 'I') {
                            MainActivity.currentPosition = selEnd + 2;
                            this.setSelection(MainActivity.currentPosition);
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
```